# Monotone divergent function diverges to infinity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(a,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is monotonically increasing.

How to show:

If 
 $f$ diverges as $x \to \infty$
then $f$ must diverge to $\infty$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: I think you are missing some conditions.

Comment: @copper.hat/ I think divergent & monotone increasing imlies diverges to infinity.

Comment: last version is ok..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well , divergence to infinity as $x\to \infty$ means that :

$\forall M$  $\exists $b such that $x>b$ implies $f(x)>M$.

And you know that given $M$ there is some b with $f(b)>M$.

[Otherwise , we would have boundedness on $[a+\varepsilon,\infty)$ which would imply

convergence as $x\to \infty$ as a result of monotonicity.]

But $f$ being monotonic increasing , we also have  $f(x)>M$ for all $x>b$.

So we conclude that $\lim _{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty $. $\hspace{64mm} $$\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry for the late reply.